# Nested-sets only for categories or for end-elements too?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nested-sets

Does nested-sets model suit only for categories/catalogs (e.g fruits, vegetables), or for end-elements too (such as apple, onion etc.)?

Let's imagine my website is selling fruits and vegetables, and it has categories of products like:

```
Products -> Fruits -> Apple, Orange, Grape
Products -> Vegetables -> Onion, Carrot
```

Apple, Orange, Grape, Onion, Carrot - are not categories of anything so they have no children (and won't have ever).

The question is should I include Apple, Orange, Grape, Onion, Carrot in my Nested-sets table or in separate one with link to its category_id? 
(e.g. the scheme of table of products would be like [id, name, price, category_id]).

Comment: It should work (as if those are leaf nodes)... but... why would you put apple inside the categories table?

Comment: That's the question itself - I want to know is Nested-sets table is only for categories OR for all my products with their parent categories.

Comment: I mean if I knew the Nested-sets table is only for categories of course I wouldn't put apple to it.

Comment: I think it should be like - Category ( Fruits and Vegetables ) and Categories Product ( Apple, Orange, Grape, Onion & Carrot  )... category product will be liked with category_id in the category product table.